# How to make an invisible internet explorer?

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, hidden

I have been playing around with VB today and was wondering on the concept of being able to load a webpage in this case radio 1 online player and but having no open browsers visible to the user even though there will be one hidden one in this case this one. Currently I have it set up to simply navigate to the site but was wondering if it was possible to do what was stated above.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Try


        Dim QueryAddress As New StringBuilder()

        QueryAddress.Append("http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/player/bbc_radio_one")


        Process.Start(QueryAddress.ToString())
        Visible = False

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Unable to station")

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: You could drop a browser control in your form and make your form invisible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play a radio station you might be better using media player and connecting to the station's radio stream.

Drop windows media player onto your form.

Set its Visible property to False.

add a button with this code inside the button's click event

```
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "http://a.files.bbci.co.uk/media/live/manifesto/audio/simulcast/hls/uk/sbr_med/llnw/bbc_radio_one.m3u8"
```

And of course your try..catch code as well.

Tada!

I got the url from [this website](http://www.radiofeeds.co.uk/mp3.asp) by clicking on the link in the second colum and then right clicking on the data rate that I wanted and copying the linked addres. I then pasted it into the vb.net code that you see